# DataBinder.Eval as ID does not work with href

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, data-binding

I am generating panel dynamically using a ListView control.  I'm trying to use Bootstrap collapsible panels.  The problem I'm having is using the DataBinder.Eval as the id of the collapsible panel body.  I am assuming that the href is correct because if I hard-code the id rather than use the DataBinder.Eval, the panel opens and closes correctly, but when I substitute the hard-coded id for the DataBinder.Eval the panel does not open.  Here is my HTML:

```
    <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#<%#Eval("ModuleKey") %>"><%#Eval("ModuleKey") %></a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
              <div id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ModuleKey")%>' class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>

              </div>
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does the generated html look like?

Comment: When looking at generated HTML the id has a space behind the name.  That is probably the problem.  Now I just have to figure out how to remove the space.  Thanks, that was the problem.